# UICollectionViewCell Cannot assign value to CustomCollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I created a custom UICollectionViewCell and I tried to reference it from `UICollectionView` `delegate` method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and I keep getting `Cannot assign value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' to type 'GridViewCell'`

## Delegate Method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    var cell = GridViewCell()

    //Deque an GridViewCell
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.representedAssetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier


    return cell
}
```

## GridViewCell class

```
import UIKit

class GridViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var thumbnailImage = UIImage()
var representedAssetIdentifier = NSString()

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.imageView.image = nil
}

//func setThumbnailImage(thumbnailImage: UIImage) {
//    self.imageView.image = thumbnailImage
//}
}
```

Comment: have you assigned GridViewCell class in identity inspector of storyboard cell?

Comment: I have done that. And re-checked if I've again and again

Comment: var cell:CustomTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell") as? CustomTableViewCell
if cell  == nil{
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
        }

Comment: this is working in case of tableview try in same way

Comment: It's a `Collectionview` not a `TableView`

Comment: I told you to try in same way as casting.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

With

```
cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GridViewCell
```